# How to write COPY for New Keys in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use AutoHotKey to do COPY, CUT and PASTE

On my Keyboard there 5 keys called A, B, C, D, E on top of F2-F6

I want to use

> A for COPY
>
> B for CUT
>
> C for PASTE

[image]

I used Key History to identify these keys

Here are the Key History Result

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-------------------------------------------------
FF  112     d   2.63    not found       
FF  112     u   0.00    not found       
FF  113     d   0.23    not found       
FF  113     u   0.00    not found       
FF  114     d   0.80    not found       
FF  114     u   0.00    not found       
FF  112     d   0.89    not found       
FF  112     u   0.02    not found       
FF  113     d   0.22    not found       
FF  113     u   0.01    not found       
FF  114     d   0.30    not found       
FF  114     u   0.02    not found       
FF  112     d   0.44    not found       
FF  112     u   0.00    not found       
FF  113     d   0.22    not found       
FF  113     u   0.00    not found       
FF  114     d   0.27    not found       
FF  114     u   0.00    not found       
FF  112     d   0.45    not found       
FF  112     u   0.00    not found       
FF  113     d   0.22    not found       
FF  113     u   0.00    not found       
FF  114     d   0.26    not found       
FF  114     u   0.00    not found       
74  03F     d   4.44    F5              
Press [F5] to refresh.
```

So

> A is SC 112

> B is SC 113

> C is SC 114

How to write the AutoHotKey for these??

Comment: See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 0x464e

I found the answer

I can combine SC with the key SC from Key History file.

so the

> A will be SC112
>
> B will be SC113
>
> C will be SC114